# DocumentApp: takes very long time to clear the current document (60+ seconds)?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google Document of 33 pages.
I need to clear the document content and replace it with something else.

The code I use is:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().clear();
```

When I run this line of code, it takes a few seconds for the code to be completed. So far so good.

However, the Document screen freezes and it takes over 60 seconds before the screen is refreshed. After about 30 seconds the Chrome browser asks me to Wait or Kill the browser tab (and I select Wait).

The Chrome task manager shows at rest 312 MB memory is in use. When running the above command the CPU jumps to 107% and stays there, memory grows to 970 MB. Using Chrome v56, same type of behavior for Safari.

When I press the (Google Documents) undo button, it only takes about a second to bring all the text back.

**What is the recommended way to empty the current document?**

**update**: it seems it is related to formatting. The document is copy-pasted from a Word document, including some formatting (typeface, color, bold).

- **test 1**: paste as text-only in Google Document (Edit > Paste without formatting). Running the clear() command takes about a second.
- **test 2**: regular copy-paste (the original test from this post), which keeps the formatting. Running the clear() command takes 60+ seconds.
- **test 3**: regular copy-paste and then use `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().setAttributes` to set bold/italic/typeface/size/color to default values. This way it looks similar to the text-only version. Takes about 2 seconds. Then run the clear() command, which still takes 60+ seconds.
- **test 4**: regular copy-paste. Then Cmd-A and Delete, which takes 5-6 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps the `clear` method works element by element, destroying each in turn, and the browser is trying to re-render it in the process... What happens if you clear it without having the document open in your browser, using  `DocumentApp.getDocumentById('your_id').getBody().clear();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an alternative way.

```
var myDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
myDoc.editAsText().deleteText(1, myDoc.getText().length-1);
```

Comment: Has same behavior. And, this would ignore non-text elements (images, horizontal rule, etc.). BTW. deleteText uses 0-based index.